# Merge without loosing rows and no duplicate if more than one match `on` and keep matching till a certain point?

Tags: python, pandas

So here is what I am trying to do:

```
df1
        symbol   qty    
 0      DA       400
 1      IND      30
 2      FY       1200    
 3      SHTV     8    
 4      HIN      40    
 5      NM       8    
 6      GRI      400    
 7      PN       7000

df2
tsym symbol quantity
PN35  PN    -3500
FY10  FY    -100
FY15  FY    -300
PN34  PN    -3500
```

When I merge them

`posdf1 = pd.merge(df2,df1,how='outer',on='symbol')`

The output I get:

```
posdf1
tsym symbol quantity qty
PN35  PN    -3500    7000
FY10  FY    -100     1200
FY15  FY    -300     1200
PN34  PN    -3500    7000
```

I am trying to find a way to get the following output 2 types of output:

```
posdf1
tsym symbol quantity qty
PN35  PN    -3500    3500
FY10  FY    -100     100
FY15  FY    -300     300
PN34  PN    -3500    3500
```

Second scenario if:

```
df2
tsym symbol quantity
PN35  PN    -7000
FY10  FY    -1200
FY15  FY    -1200
PN34  PN    -7000
```

then desired output:

```
posdf1
tsym symbol quantity qty
PN35  PN    -7000    7000
FY10  FY    -1200    1200
FY15  FY    -300     NaN
PN34  PN    -7000    NaN
```

I can loop through the dataframe and get the above results I think. I am just trying to figure out if `merge` or some other `pandas` trick can be used here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain your two types of outputs?

Comment: In the first scenario, it looks like you're just taking the absolute value of the existing column, so `df2['qty']=df2['quantity'].abs()`, no merging required. For the second, where are the `NaN`'s coming from?

Comment: @ScottBoston In the second case, when the quantity in from df1 is used up then NaN if match is found.

Comment: @G.Anderson when `df['qty']` quantity is used up i.e. 7000 matched to -7000 then no more matches are to be made hence the NaN

Comment: Where does that -300 in the final dataframe come from?

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like neither of your described use cases use the data from `df1` at all.
Given the dataframe

```
df2=pd.DataFrame({'tsym':['PN35','FY10','FY15','PN34'],
                 'symbol':['pn','fy','fy','pn'], 
                 'quantity':[-3500,-100,-300,-3500]})

    tsym    symbol  quantity
0   PN35    pn      -3500
1   FY10    fy      -100
2   FY15    fy      -300
3   PN34    pn      -3500
```

For the first scenario:

```
df2['qty']=df2['quantity'].abs()

    tsym    symbol  quantity qty
0   PN35    pn      -3500    3500
1   FY10    fy      -100     100
2   FY15    fy      -300     300
3   PN34    pn      -3500    3500
```

For the second, you can make a temporary `groupby().first()` df and merge it back to the original:

```
df2=pd.DataFrame({'tsym':['PN35','FY10','FY15','PN34'],
                 'symbol':['pn','fy','fy','pn'], 
                 'quantity':[-7000,-1200,-1200,-7000]})

df3=df2.groupby('symbol').first().reset_index()

df3['qty']=df3['quantity'].abs()

df2=df2.merge(df3,how='outer')

df2

    tsym    symbol  quantity    qty
0   PN35    pn      -7000       7000.0
1   FY10    fy      -1200       1200.0
2   FY15    fy      -1200       NaN
3   PN34    pn      -7000       NaN
```